# i am not able to print the values of pixels of my image using python

Tags: python, opencv, pixel, raster

I am trying to calculate the pixels of a raster image using python, and i found this code in the website:

```py
path4 = "./bmp.bmp"
brownbox= cv2.imread(path4)
brownkbox=cv2.resize(brownbox, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
brownbox2_gray= cv2.cvtColor(brownbox, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("gray",brownbox2_gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

rows,cols = brownbox2_gray.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        print (k)

k values are not being printed? only the images are shown
```

Comment: have you tried `print(k)`? It looks like your example you're following is `python2` while you're running `python3`

Comment: i tried that, but still i am not getting the pixels values

Comment: what is your output then?

Comment: it is just showing me the image after i converted it into grayscale

Comment: from the code that you've provided, that isn't possible. Please provide a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: brownbox= cv2.imread(path4)
brownkbox=cv2.resize(brownbox, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
brownbox2_gray= cv2.cvtColor(brownbox, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rows,cols = brownbox.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        k = img[i,j]
        assert isinstance(k, object)
        print (k)

Comment: you still don't have an `imshow` anywhere. What is your console output

Comment: This is the first part of the code

Comment: path4 = "./bmp.bmp"
brownbox= cv2.imread(path4)
brownkbox=cv2.resize(brownbox, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
brownbox2_gray= cv2.cvtColor(brownbox, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
brownbox2_gray_canny= cv2.Canny(brownbox2_gray,30,30)

cv2.imshow("gray",brownbox2_gray)
cv2.imshow("canny",brownbox2_gray_canny)
cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: @python_3 don't post your code as a comment. Update your original post with all of your code. Make it easy for people to want to help you.

Comment: Thank you i will do that

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open('name of your jpg.jpg')
array = np.asarray(i)
print(array)
```